# Highcharts Highstock: crosshairs move with figure swipe rather than tapping on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/crosshair-snap-false/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Non-snapped crosshair'
    },
    xAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            snap: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            snap: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
});
```

I find an example as shown above. The crosshairs move along with mouse pointer and the value is shown in the tooltip. However, if I run this example on IPad safari or chrome, the crosshairs disappear or stayed on the original position. It does not follow the finger tip and the problem is I need to tap on each point to initiate the value popup. So, if there any method to control this.? I want the crosshair move with the finger tip rather than tapping on each point to make the tooltip popup.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do it?

Comment: No, sorry......